# What means 100% accept rate under my icon in my question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

What does this mean?

> 100% accept rate

It's under my user info in my questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means of the questions you have asked which also have answers, you have Accepted an answer on 100% of them.

Questions with no answers do not count in this calculation.

Comment: I think you have to have asked a minimum of 4 questions too.

Comment: It also means you are a good human being, and when the zombie apocalypse comes you will be eaten last :-)